# vscode run as different user in Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

so few months ago I started using VScode. Im pretty amazed by the functionalities it offers
through lots of extensions available and configurability.

Few days ago I encountered this error, I installed VScode as user1, everything works, but when trying to run vscode as another user (user2) I get this error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir".
I was hoping that all settings, snippets and extensions will be available to all the users on the machine, but apparenly I'm missing something even when running as another user. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently VScode is not concepted like this. Every user should have its own settings folder (*~/.config/Code/User*) and extension folder (*~/.vscode/extensions*). In order to sync settings and extensions between users simple copy/paste should do or some sync extension can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the SSH extension from user1's account and SSH to user2@0.0.0.0, that way I think you'll be using user1's local VScode settings but will be logged in as user2